# image crop with gd then upload to db but not resizing

Tags: php, gd

My code basically should crop the image to 219px by 127px and save the image to the database but I'm getting errors and can't figure it out.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnupload']) && $_FILES['imglogo']['size'] > 0) {


$tmpname = $_FILES['imglogo']['tmp_name'];
$imgsize = $security->secure($_FILES['imglogo']['size']);
$imgtype = $security->secure($_FILES['imglogo']['type']);
$school = $security->secure($_POST['school']);

//crop image
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(219,127);
$imgattrib = getimagesize($tmpname);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpname);
imagecopyresized($canvas,$source,0,0,0,0,219,127,$imgattrib[0],$imgattrib[1]);

$handle = fopen($tmpname, "r");
$content = fread($handle, filesize($tmpname));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($handle);




$save = mysql_query("insert into tbl_school_preview  values(null,'$school','$content','$imgtype','$imgsize')") or die(mysql_error());
//header("Location: school-catalog.php?page=school_preview");
}
?>
```

I don't see any errors but the crop isn't happening. Do I have something wrong?

[Updated code]
Here is the new piece of block for some reason the thumb won't save.

```
if(isset($_POST['btnupload']) && $_FILES['imglogo']['size'] > 0) {

//$filename = $security->secure($_FILES['imgschool']['name']);
$tmpname = $_FILES['imglogo']['tmp_name'];
$imgsize = $security->secure($_FILES['imglogo']['size']);
$imgtype = $security->secure($_FILES['imglogo']['type']);
$school = $security->secure($_POST['school']);

//crop image
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(219,127);
$imgattrib = getimagesize($tmpname);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpname);
imagecopyresized($canvas,$source,0,0,0,0,219,127,$imgattrib[0],$imgattrib[1]);



$newfile = imagejpeg($canvas,'thumb.jpg',100);

$handle = fopen($newtmpfile, "r");
$content = fread($newtmpfile, filesize($newtmpfile));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($handle);




$save = mysql_query("insert into tbl_school_preview values(null,'$school','$content','$imgtype','$imgsize')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: "im getting errors and cant figure it out." errors? would you share them with us ?

Comment: "im getting errors" & "i dont see any errors". Which is it? What errors are you getting?

Comment: actually i was getting errors while i was posting this threat then i looked over the code again and saw that i just needed to remove some variables that i wasn't using anymore. and just forgot the rename the title. here ill take care of it now. thnx

Answer (score 0):

You should save the content of $canvas, not the content of the original image.

Output it to temporary file with [imagepng](http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php), or directly output stream, which you will then have to intercept.

ob_start();

imagepng($canvas);

$out = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

Comment: your actually right but where would $canvas be put? in the $handle variable like this? $handle = fopen($canvas, "r"); that iddnt work and i dont see how it would grab an image like that. if u dont mind can you point it out for me :)   im trying to figure out as of now also   thnx.

Comment: You must be saving to a write-protected directory. The current directory.

Comment: You can also get away without temp file. See the updated answer.

Comment: i got it to work like this: $content = addslashes(ob_get_contents()); thanks alot dude!!!!... but what does ob_start and ob_getcontents do? whats their purpose in this? thnx

Comment: They buffer the output stream until you do either flush or clean. imagepng without filename outputs to the output stream. Then you grab buffer's content and discard the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any fopen / fwrite stuff to save your image.  Replace all that with something like:

```
$filename = '/path/to/desired/save/location.png'
imagepng($canvas, $filename);
```

And you should be good to go.  The imagepng function will write the file when you give it the second parameter.  Same would be true for imagegif and imagejpeg.

Answer (score 0):

*Just two tips:*

I would first of all not to save the file to the filesystem.. You can use [ob_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) to get the content of the file.

```
ob_start();
imagepng($canvas);
$imageString = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$save = mysql_query("
    insert into tbl_school_preview    
    values(null,'$school',$imagestring,'$imgtype','$imgsize')
    ")or die(mysql_error());
```

Also use [imagecopyresampled()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) for better quality of the thumbnail. Beware of strange characters in the image code when inserting into the database.